# Are product metafields included when fetching an order from Shopify via the API?

Tags: shopify

We are building an app to pull orders from Shopify and import them into a third-party system. As part of this we need to access metafield data for the products. Is this included in the product details returned by the API call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.. if you pull a Product, Order or any other resource with an API call, you'll need to pull the metafields if any are associated with that resource with a separate call. Same thing with the metafields assigned to Variants, or any other resources. They are always a separate API call.